# ¿Cómo obtener JSON desde una URL?

Tags: php, json, xml

Buenas, tengo una pregunta, creo que sencilla estoy tratando de traer datos de un json que obtengo desde un url, trato de cargarlos con un json_decode, pero solo me devuelve "bool(false)" como respuesta, estoy intentando hacer un xml con eso, pero no logro sacar los datos.

```
$url = "http://dev.webilation.com/memeimporter/api/getArticles";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump ( $xml);
```

quisiera poder pasar esa data a array, pero si no puedo cargar sus datos se me hace imposible. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías obtener los datos mediante la función **[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)** y una vez obtenidos los datos hacer un **[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)** para poder decodificar el JSON.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://dev.webilation.com/memeimporter/api/getArticles";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    var_dump($obj);
```

Esto me ha devuelto 18 resultados en el array.

Si quisieras recorrer cada uno de los elementos del array que te devuelve el JSON podrías realizar un bucle **[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)**. En este caso, yo saco los títulos de todos los artículos por pantalla:

```
foreach($obj as $o){
    echo nl2br($o["title"] . "\n");
}
```

**Nota**: La función **[`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php)** la utilizo para que me respete los saltos de línea que añado después de cada título de artículo.

Comment: cuando quiero sacar los valores por separado, me dice null, como sería en ese caso? @FranciscoRomero

Comment: @JuanRomero ¿A que te refieres a obtener los valores por separado? ¿A obtener cada uno de los elementos del array?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero, si haces [`json_decode($json, true)`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) obtendrás un arreglo asociativo, el cual siempre es mas fácil de iterar.

Comment: @Marcos Nada que un bucle `foreach` no pueda subsanar (en mi opinión).

Answer (score 0):

conseguí una forma de poder visualizar los datos.

```
$url = "http://dev.webilation.com/memeimporter/api/getArticles";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$prueba = json_decode($xml);
var_dump ( $prueba);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar `file_get_contents()` tienes que configurar en tu `php.ini` y aceptar `allow_url_fopen`:

```
; Deshabilitar allow_url_fopen por razones de seguridad (on/off)
allow_url_fopen = on
```

Si no queremos cambiar o no te dejan cambiar `allow_url_fopen` podemos usar

- [`curl - documentación`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

Con `curl` tienes un multitud de opciones que puedes usar, pero te dejo uno básico:

```
$url = 'http://dev.webilation.com/memeimporter/api/getArticles';

//  Iniciamos curl
$curl = curl_init();
// Desactivamos verificación SSL
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
// Devuelve respuesta aunque sea falsa
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
// Especificamo los MIME-Type que son aceptables para la respuesta.
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Accept: application/json' ] );
// Establecemos la URL
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
// Ejecutmos curl
$json = curl_exec( $curl );
// Cerramos curl
curl_close( $curl );
$respuestas = json_decode( $json, true );

var_dump( $respuestas );
```